# Overlaying jQuery Modal over iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an iframe that has a Modal in it,

Is there a way for me to display the Modal dialog **over** the iFrame width/height?

So let's say my iframe is 200x200 and my modal is 300x300, is it possible to display the modal 'outside' the iframe bounds without appending the modal to the parent page?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible - not without some form of messaging from your `iframe` hosted code to the parent page.

Comment: I have control over both pages, however I do want to load the modal div inside the iframe and not move/load it on the parent page, does that help me in any way?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `iframe` in this case. If you want to get control of other page in `iframe`, use some div. You can use [$.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to get the content of other page. Then you can control watever way you want.